# I introduced an ambiguous reference between iTextSharp.text.Rectangle and System.Drawing.Rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

After I add the following `using` statements to my code, I get plenty of ambiguous reference errors:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

This is a screen shot of the errors:

[image: Example]

Does anybody know what's causing these errors? How I can introduce iTextSharp and avoid these errors?

Comment: did you added the reference from `NuGet` or manually added it?

Comment: it seems that conflict between two versions of the same reference..

Comment: I added it with nuget

Comment: Looks like it's predominantly a naming conflict with `System.Drawing`. Remove `using System.Drawing` and/or create an alias for one of them.

Comment: @CharlesMager I just saw that now

Comment: But Thank you 
I Used:
    System.Drawing.Rectangle
for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are experiencing something that is very normal and that no developer would describe as "creating errors." When a developer writes C# code, he creates classes in a certain namespace. For instance: at iText, we created classes such as `Font` in the namespace `iTextSharp.text`.

Obviously, the class name `Font` isn't very original, there are other libraries that use the same name *in a different namespace*. There's even a class named `Font` in the C# programming language, more specifically in the namespace `System.Drawing`.

That is perfectly OK. A compiler can easily see the difference between `iTextSharp.text.Font` and `System.Drawing.Font` because they have a different *fully qualified name* (that is: the full name of the class, including the namespace).

In your code, you confuse the compiler. You add a `using` statement, that allows the compiler to use the `iTextSharp.text.Font` class. However, when you use the `Font` class in your code, you don't specify which `Font` class you intend to use. Your compiler is asking you: do you mean to use `iTextSharp.text.Font` or `System.Drawing.Font`? And also: do you mean to use `iTextSharp.text.Rectangle` or `System.Drawing.Rectangle`?

You can solve this problem by using the fully qualified name so that the compiler is no longer confused.

For instance, without the namespace, your compiler doesn't know if you meant:

```
pnlReport.DrawToBitMap(bm, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
```

or:

```
pnlReport.DrawToBitMap(bm, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
```

So you have to use:

```
pnlReport.DrawToBitMap(bm, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
```

instead of:

```
pnlReport.DrawToBitMap(bm, Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
```

You can also use namespace aliases like:

```
using sys = System.Drawing;
```

to simplify callings like this:

```
pnlReport.DrawToBitMap(bm, new sys.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
```

Comment: You can also use namespace aliases like  *using sys =  System.Drawing;* to simplify callings (would be *pnlReport.DrawToBitMap(bm, new sys.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));* then)

Comment: Thanks, I added your comment to my answer.